# Why did Ramunajacharya say that Devas were corporeal?

Tags: scripture, gods, ramanujacharya, body, interpretation

According to Ramanuja:

> Pragâpati with fuel in their hands, staying with him as pupils for thirty-two years, &c. (Kh. Up. VIII, 7 ff.), clearly shows that the devas possess bodies and sense-organs. Analogously, mantras and arthavâdas, which are complementary to injunctions of works, contain unmistakeable references to the corporeal nature of the gods ('Indra holding in his hand the thunderbolt'; 'Indra lifted the thunderbolt', &c.); and as the latter is not contradicted by any other means of proof it must be accepted on the authority stated.
>
> [Ramanujacharya](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48124.htm)

However, I do not see how this belief is compatible with Scripture. The devas create the material universe, and they could not do that if they are material themselves. Also, the devas can hear our thoughts, which are soundless, which shows they are not confined to their bodies. And if they are not confined to their bodies, then they have no need of a body except when appearing to humans.

Also, the devas have the ability to work certain wonders without means of a body part, which they could not do if they were corporeal.

For example, devas are present in consecrated idols. Now if devas has physical bodies, then in order to be present in idols, their physical body would have to be in the idol. But this is not true, so the devas cannot have physical bodies.

Comment: you have juxtaposed and conflated several different ideas together with your own assumptions which you state as true, and then drawn a deductive conclusion, which I think is erroneous. I would say 'onus probandi'. Scripture does not say the gods created the universe, where does it say the devas can hear our thoughts, read our minds, scripture does not say they have physical bodies, etc, etc.

Comment: Why do you interpret 'fuel' as 'physical'? The subtle body has the same parts as the physical body, including hands....

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda What do you mean when you say that the subtle body has hands and other body parts?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda So are the body parts on subtle bodies analogous to the body parts on physical bodies? So the "hand" on a subtle body is analogical with physical hands?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda As in, the "hands" and "feet" of devas are called so because they share a similar function to our hands and feet?

Comment: This is mere confusion. Nowhere it is said that devas created the universe. Know that you are reading the Brahmasūtras, in Vedānta devas aren't the creators. They possess bodies, which is said to be valid on the basis of their accounts from itihāsa texts. No matter how high and mighty they appear, still they are not the ultimate cause and essence of the universe, in the case of Vedānta.

Comment: 1.3.27 and its commentaries answer you question further. If devas have bodies, they may  be expected to be present like priests on the occasion of sacrifice. How could Indra be present in multiple sacrifices, if they are performed at the same time? In answer, it is stated that one and the same deity can assume various forms at the same time. Br̥hadāraṇyakopaniṣad (III.9.1-2) indicates that one and the same divine Self may appear in many forms simultaneously.

Comment: Another solution to this issue is offered by some commentators, that just as a priest cannot be fed by different people at the same time but can still be saluted by all, a deva can without leaving his place be the common object of reverence of many and also give offerings to them. The embodiedness of the gods is thus in no way a hindrance to their sacrificial activities. Another view may be that just like the same teacher is saluted simultaneously by many worshippers so different performers of sacrifice  may give their offerings to one and the same corporeal deity who abides in his own place.

Comment: So, actually, 1.3.26-27 in Brahmasūtras and its commentators including Rāmānuja don't go against the scriptures when they say that the devas are embodied. **Also, embodied doesn't mean material necessarily.**

Comment: @Bingming I'm not talking about the whole universe, I'm talking about the material universe.
And if Devas can take on multiple forms, then you are already implicitly assuming a separation between the deva and any particular body, which leads to the idea that devas are essentially incorporeal.

Comment: @Bingming What is an immaterial body like? Does it have shape, size, or location?

Comment: Even the material universe, where is it said that they are the creators? It doesn't say so anywhere in the Brahmasūtras or in the Upaniṣads or in Bhagavad Gītā. Also, I am not saying all this, what I wrote above, I was just mentioning again what sūtra and its commentaries say. 
Your idea of body is restricted to physical human body. That is why you are facing so much problem in understanding the idea.

Comment: There are  three types of bodies here, kāraṇa śarīra (causal body), sūkṣma śarīra (subtle body) and sthūla śarīra (gross body). The material physical body is the sthula śarīra. Devas don't have that, since if they had that, then there would be no difference b/w them and men/women.

Comment: @Bingming Do plants and animals have sthūla śarīra?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141456/discussion-between-terjij-kassal-and-bingming).